# Python gethostby.name takes too long

Tags: python, networking

I am working on a network scanner that processes the output from zgrab2 for about 800 records. Each record has an IP and information for 7 ports. Each record is stored as a JSON/line in a separate file. The code performs some reverse DNS and DNS checks to verify the data as much as I can. To do so each record is processed using a combination of try-except blocks and the information needed is stored.

Upon profiling my script that does the data processing and analysis I found that gethostbyname takes the most amount of time and is affecting the speed of the code. Attached below is a screenshot of the cProfile I did for my script.

I am not sure why gethostbyname is taking so long. Is it because it is using my local DNS?

I came across using Google Public DNS for name resolutions as a faster alternative but I am not sure how to go about this. Any guidance on this and why it is taking so much time will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[cProfile stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uogwD.png)

Comment: "_I found that gethostbyname takes the most amount of time_" As well it should because it is querying a server to get the data. You will have the network latency (in both directions) and ther server processing time. That is an inherently slow process.

Comment: Is there a way around it I can use? It is affecting my program run time significantly. I was thinking maybe having a separate thread for that while the other processing continues?

Comment: As glacially slow as python already is, waiting for a response to a network request is going to be even slower. You could, of course, run a DNS server on the machine hosting the Python application. That would really only be the way to speed that up. By the way, using a remote DNS sever, e.g. Google, would normally be slower than using a local DNS server.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. I found a tool called massdns [1](https://github.com/blechschmidt/massdns). Would this be faster for simple DNS lookups than gethostbyname?